# BigQuery - Android Purchase Attribution

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4, attribution

I'm trying to replicate GA4/Firebase traffic & user acquisition reports for mobile apps using BigQuery.

I'm using this simple query to check the number of users, new users and purchasers for a specific day.

```
 select
  traffic_source.medium,
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) users,
  count(distinct case when event_name= "first_open" then user_pseudo_id end ) as new_users,
  count(case when event_name= "purchase" then user_pseudo_id end ) as purchasers
from
     'mytable.events_*`
 where platform='ANDROID' 
 group by 1
 order by 1
```

Here are my BigQuery results:

[image]

However, they do not match the data from GA4 explorer reports:

[image]

The number of new users matches well, however, the distribution of purchasers is completely off.

Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Many thanks:)

Comment: Hello! I suggest reducing your date range to less than 90 days and checking the discrepancy again. If it is fixed, it is likely due to the conversion window in GA4, which considers sources only from up to 90 days ago by default.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response:) The data I checked was for one day only, so not sure if  the discrepancy is caused by the attribution differences